# What does it mean that StAX parsers aren't complete or correct?

Tags: xml, parsing

I've been browsing the net and found theses two slides on site of XOM (XML object model):

- [slide1](http://www.xom.nu/whatswrong/img3.html)
- [slide2](http://www.xom.nu/whatswrong/img4.html)

Where they refer to SAX(push) and StAX(pull) parsers. So I'm wondering, what does it mean that a StAX parser isn't complete or correct in practice?

Comment: Have you tried emailing the author of the slides for clarification? ([Elliotte Harold](http://www.xom.nu/whatswrong/whatswrong.html)). (If you get a response, perhaps you could post it as an answer here)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question!  The site of the author is especially interesting. Have a look at his interview wih artima, where he classifys the different kind of XML APIs. Personally these days I favor the fifth kind-LINQ to XML.

Comment: @John: Yes, I mailed him as per your advice, but so far I had no reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comment was aimed more generally at the pull-based XML APIs and parsers of the time, not just StAX and its implementations. At the time the slide deck was written (over ten years ago!), there were known deficiencies with XMLPULL API design regarding the handling of namespaces and ill-formed documents – in fact, it was Rusty Harold himself who [reported them](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/08/14/xmlpull.html?page=2)! Also, StAX was in its infancy ([JSR 173](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) did not hit final release until 2004), and other implementations were apparently not yet considered mature.

Ten years is a long time in the software world, and things may well have changed in the intervening time. If you want to know what the current state of the art is for a particular parser or set of parsers, you should ask about it. See for example this [much more recent exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878143/comparison-between-woodstox-and-sjsxp), and questions with the [stax tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stax), on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As I received no answer from Harold and this seems like a decent answer, I'm accepting it.